# @SkipValidation only for one parameter

Tags: validation, struts2, annotations

I have define the following validators:

```
@Validations(
    customValidators = {
        @CustomValidator(fieldName="campaignId", type="long", key="campaign.required", parameters={@ValidationParameter(name="min", value="1")}),
        @CustomValidator(fieldName="campaignType", type="long", key="campaignType.required", parameters={@ValidationParameter(name="min", value="1")})
    }
)
```

i need to skip validation only for the "campaignType" parameter on one action. I tried with @SkipValidation  but its skips both parameters  .

Comment: Why do you need to skip on second type?

Comment: i have 2 action in one class.
1. create Campaign (need to set both parameters)
2. display Campaing (only the campaignId parameter is needed)

Comment: Put validators on action methods, two on 1st action and one on 2nd.